# Library which provides iterate_months(start_date, end_date) method

Tags: python

Is there python library for python which provides an `iterate_months(start_date, end_date)` method?

Here is an answer which contains such a method: [Generate list of months between interval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34899198/633961).

Comment: Why not taking the code from there and saving it into a file, so you can simply `import` the method – if you only need that? What makes that different from a library?

Comment: I was told to avoid redundancy and copy+paste. That's why I would like to use a library. Even if the library just provides one simple method.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. Take the code posted there, save it into a file (in the appropriate location), and you have your library.